# applicationWillTerminate not called when application in applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

Application is not calling `applicationWillTerminate` when the app is in `applicationDidEnterBackground` state.

Means i click on home button then the app goes to `applicationDidEnterBackground` but when i decide to double click on home button and remove (by swipe up) it does not call the `applicationWillTerminate`.

Why it is not calling?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez the answer is not in swift language i want this in swift

Comment: Your question is about the behaviour of iOS itself, so the language being used isn't relevant here. @EmilioPelaez's link should help you

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Yeah it works after converting to swift language online